# Removing the annotation( 1e^x ) on top of the yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm generating plots with matplotlib. By default matplotlib adds an "1e" annotation on the top of the y-axis when the values are large. But since i have another axis on the top of my plot, this annotation overlaps with it. I need either turn it iff or move it to the left, So that It doesn't overlap with the x axis.

The image should make things clear (see link below). I'm interested in getting rid of overlap on the top left part of the figure.

I looked in the documentation, but I couldn't find anything that could turn it off. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can influence the format of the tick labels using `plt.ticklabel_format`. In particular, you can call `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` to disable the offset that you don't like. This and other parameters are [explained in the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format).

Comment: Not sure how I missed that when I went through the documentation. I'll accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` is only useful when you want to remove notation from x-axis. If you want remove the notation from y-axis then use `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')` and if you want to remove it from both then use `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain', axis='both')`.

Comment: This is incorrect. To toggle which axis is affected, you use the `axis` kwarg. For example: `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain', axis='both')` where `axis` can be "x", "y", or "both". See the docs here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format

Comment: @PaulH Okay, you are right, but `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')` also works.

Comment: Your distinction on how to modify the x- and y-axes individually is still misleading